# Website is showing up as part text and part html on PC

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I was searching for C programs on the net and I landed on this [program](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/calculating-area-of-circle-using.html):

```
<span style='color:#004a43'>#</span><span style='color:#004a43'>include</span><span style='color:#800000'>&lt;</span><span style='color:#40015a'>stdio.h</span><span style='color:#800000'>&gt;</span>

<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>void</span> areaperi <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>int</span> r<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>float</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span>a<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>float</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span>p <span style='color:#308080'>)</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>{</span>
<span style='color:#308080'>*</span>a <span style='color:#308080'>=</span> <span style='color:#008000'>3.14</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> r <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> r <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#308080'>*</span>p <span style='color:#308080'>=</span> <span style='color:#008c00'>2</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> <span style='color:#008000'>3.14</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> r <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>}</span>

<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>void</span> <span style='color:#400000'>main</span><span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#308080'>)</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>{</span>
<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>int</span> radius <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>float</span> area<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> perimeter <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>

<span style='color:#003060'>printf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>n</span><span style='color:#1060b6'>Enter radius of a circle </span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span> <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#003060'>scanf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>%d</span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#308080'>&amp;</span>radius <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>

areaperi <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> radius<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#308080'>&amp;</span>area<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#308080'>&amp;</span>perimeter <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>

<span style='color:#003060'>printf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#1060b6'>Area = </span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>%f</span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#308080'>,</span> area <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#003060'>printf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>n</span><span style='color:#1060b6'>Perimeter = </span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>%f</span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#308080'>,</span> perimeter <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>}</span>
```

I opened it on my phone and it opened properly but it shows some part text and some part html on my pc.

I wanted to know why this was happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That "c4learn.com" site is broken, and I don't see it working on a phone either.

They meant to publish a syntax-highlighted listing of the C program, but instead they published *the HTML source code* for the syntax-highlighted listing.

To see the C program, you need to "run" the HTML source code. You can do this by saving it to an HTML file and opening the file in your browser, or using one of the online HTML/CSS/JS editors, such as the one provided on StackOverflow (click the "Run code snippet" button below):

```html
<div style="white-space: pre">
<span style='color:#004a43'>#</span><span style='color:#004a43'>include</span><span style='color:#800000'>&lt;</span><span style='color:#40015a'>stdio.h</span><span style='color:#800000'>&gt;</span>

<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>void</span> areaperi <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>int</span> r<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>float</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span>a<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>float</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span>p <span style='color:#308080'>)</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>{</span>
<span style='color:#308080'>*</span>a <span style='color:#308080'>=</span> <span style='color:#008000'>3.14</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> r <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> r <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#308080'>*</span>p <span style='color:#308080'>=</span> <span style='color:#008c00'>2</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> <span style='color:#008000'>3.14</span> <span style='color:#308080'>*</span> r <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>}</span>

<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>void</span> <span style='color:#400000'>main</span><span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#308080'>)</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>{</span>
<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>int</span> radius <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#200080;font-weight:bold'>float</span> area<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> perimeter <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>

<span style='color:#003060'>printf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>n</span><span style='color:#1060b6'>Enter radius of a circle </span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span> <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#003060'>scanf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>%d</span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#308080'>&amp;</span>radius <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>

areaperi <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> radius<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#308080'>&amp;</span>area<span style='color:#308080'>,</span> <span style='color:#308080'>&amp;</span>perimeter <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>

<span style='color:#003060'>printf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#1060b6'>Area = </span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>%f</span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#308080'>,</span> area <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#003060'>printf</span> <span style='color:#308080'>(</span> <span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>n</span><span style='color:#1060b6'>Perimeter = </span><span style='color:#0f69ff'>%f</span><span style='color:#800000'>"</span><span style='color:#308080'>,</span> perimeter <span style='color:#308080'>)</span> <span style='color:#406080'>;</span>
<span style='color:#406080'>}</span>
</div>
```

(Note that I wrapped the code in [`<div style="white-space: pre">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to make the whitespace display properly.)